# ILMERGE error while merging multiple dlls into plugin project

Tags: ilmerge

mkdir "$(TargetDir)Merged"

I was able to merge upto Newtonsoft.Json.dll and buld successfully, but as we add Agero.Core.Checker.dll we get the exited with code 1

Comment: What version of ILMerge? Did you install it via NuGet?